# Embed HTML document inside a webpage, not from URL

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

I'm aiming to create an iframe-like window on my webpage but the iframe source is also on the same webpage, and has to be editable by the javascript on this webpage. The source is basically an entire document that I need to embed within the page.

Any help would be much appreciated, and if my wording is confusing, I apologise and I'll be glad to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found, I need to use JavaScript to dynamically edit the iframe [srcdoc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp) attribute to my html code.